# Python socket ipv6 over network not working

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, connection

I am trying to connect a server to a client in python with sockets.
The problem is that with ipv6 binding, it works on my local network. What I want is to connect it to another network. These programs are written in Python 3

Here is the code of server.py:

```
import socket

HOST = someip
PORT = someport

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

server.listen()
```

Source code of client.py:

```
import socket
HOST = someip
PORT = someport

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

I think it is a port forwarding problem.
I know the code does nothing right now, but I want to first establish the connection.

Comment: Check the settings of the router in your client and server network. IPv6 routing is often disabled by default. The ISP sometimes also requires you to submit a dedicated request to enable IPv6 if they support it at all

Comment: 1. Shot in the dark: Try if it works with IPv4. At least this would give us a hint at what's wrong. 2. This is a network issue so you have to describe to us your network layout. While we're at it: How experienced are you with routing in general?

Comment: It works on ipv4, but ipv4 is only on local network. I want it to work over different networks

Comment: Pleaser share the error message you got; in full.

Comment: @AlesTeska There is no error message, only waiting for connection and not working.

Answer (score 1):

When the server receives a request, we need to put it in a loop to accept it.
**Like this**

```
import socket

HOST = someip
PORT = someport

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))
server.listen()
while True:
    try:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        print(f"New request from {addr}")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.close()
```